# ECharts - Set options to externally loaded arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, echarts

So I am using the library [ECharts](http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/index-en.html) to create some charts and graphs for various data that I have on a website. This is my first time using the library and I am fairly new to Javascript/jQuery. What I am trying to do is set the xAxis data to the results from a local page which will return a JSON Object with an array containing the days of the week. After I can do this, I then plan to load the Series data in the same way.

The jSON that is returned is this

[image]

When I am trying to set the data for xAxis, I am doing it as shown

```
xAxis: [{
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/getData.php?test=t&graph_last_days=d&days=7",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                return result.data;
                //console.log(result.data);
            }
        });
    }

}],
```

However, I keep getting the error *Uncaught TypeError: o.slice is not a function* and this error is only being outputted when I try and use this method of setting the data. In addition to this, if I try and make a function to return the data from the external page and set a variable to that, whenever I try and print it to the console it says *undefined*

If I do not use my method of trying to load the external data and I predefine the data like so

```
xAxis: [{
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: [
        'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
    ]
}]
```

Then there are no errors and it works just fine

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that after speaking with some people, the only example usage or documentation available is this example they have which is closely related to my question [here](http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/doc-en.html#Appendix-an-Intuitive-Example).

If anyone else wants some examples related to ajax or dynamic data loading with [ECharts](http://echarts.baidu.com/index-en.html) then here are some *(in English)* *

- [Line + Bar](http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/dynamicLineBar.html#-en)
- [Scatter + Candlestick](http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/dynamicScatterK.html#-en)
- [Pie + Radar](http://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/dynamicPieRadar.html#-en)

---

**Helpful tip**

If you do not speak Chinese and you are using some sort of translator for their code examples; be aware that it's common for websites such as [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/) and [Bing Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator) to incorrectly translate the punctuation used in JS by doing things such as,

- Translating arrays with single quotes into arrays with single quotes **and** double quotes: thus causing syntax errors.
- Removing commas (,) from objects.
- Changing Semi-colon's (;) into Colon's (:) or even removing them.

Answer (score 1):

complete example for echarts pushing data from Ajax call

data.importPorts -> Array of strings
data.importBD -> Array of Objects { clientanem : [4,5,6,7,3]}

```
$.get("/Home/Graph1", { clients: "403,300", years: "2012" })
          .done(function (data) {
              var option = {
                  tooltip: {
                      show: true
                  },
                  legend: {
                      data: (function () {
                          var res = [];
                          for (var name in data.importBD) {
                              res.push(name);
                          };
                          return res;
                      })()
                  },
                  xAxis: [
                      {
                          type: 'category',
                          data: (function () {
                              var res = [];
                              data.importPorts.forEach(function (i) {
                                  res.push(i);
                              });
                              return res;
                          })()
                      }
                  ],
                  yAxis: [
                      {
                          type: 'value'
                      }
                  ],
                  series: [
                      {

                      }
                  ]
              };

              for (var name in data.importBD) {
                  var obj = {
                      name: name,
                      type: "bar",
                      data: data.importBD[name]
                  };

                  option.series.push(obj);

              }
              // Load data into the ECharts instance
              imprtChart.setOption(option);
          });
```

Comment: That's not what was asked, at all.